# Can't use NAME in form can I use ID instead?

Tags: php, forms

I am working on a project that is developed using Kohana and due to some conditions I have no access to use `NAME` in the forms instead I have an option to use `ID` but I tried using the following method which didn't work.

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
    <p><input type="text" size="30" style="border-radius:15px; border:2px solid #000; padding:5px;" placeholder="Name" id="contname" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" size="30" style="border-radius:15px; border:2px solid #000; padding:5px;" placeholder="Email" id="contemail" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" size="30" style="border-radius:15px; border:2px solid #000; padding:5px;" placeholder="Subject" id="contsubject" /><br />
    <br />
    <textarea style="border-radius:5px; border:2px solid #000; padding:5px; width:320px; height:120px;" id="contmessage" placeholder="Message"></textarea><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" style="background-color:#9377dd; border-radius:10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px; padding-left:16px; padding-right:16px;" /></p>
</form>
```

**sendmail.php**

```
<?php
$from = $_POST["contemail"];
$message = $_POST["contname"] . "<br/>". $_POST["contsubject"] . "<br/>" . $_POST["contmessage"];
mail("me@mail.com","From contact form",$message,"From: $from\n");
mail("me@mail.com","From contact form",$message,"From: $from\n");
header('Location: faq');
?>
```

**Any alternate method please???**

Comment: The alternate is to **use the name attribute**. That's what it's for. Of course you can't just *not use it*, use something completely unrelated (id), and expect it to work.

Comment: Use a library like jQuery and then build the post object manually using field `id`s and send.

Comment: None of your form elements are named. I.e.: `name="contemail"` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - That's what the issue is, I have no access to use `name` I can only use `id`. Code doesn't allow me to save with `name` tags

Comment: You probably could use jQuery for this. @lock which is an alternative. Although I never use it, I have seen similar posts here.

Answer (score 1):

When you post the form then in server side you can access that field by their name. Now you are not using the name and instead of you are using the id then I will suggest you to use javascript ajax method to post the form. This is the only alternative method is available.

Comment: Yeah, must give a try.

Answer (score 0):

When you post a form, the form is converted into key/value pairs and sent to the server. For example...

```
<input name="MyName" value="MyValue">
```

Is sent to the server as

```
MyName=MyValue
```

Unless the browser can form a key/value pair it won't send the data - this is true whether you are missing the key (from the name attribute) or a value (for example a checkbox that is not checked).

You could iterate over the form using JavaScript and create a form post using a different attribute (such as your ID), but if you have access to add JavaScript to this form, it would be easier to just add names.

Comment: A mention to say that `MyName` is not the same as `myname` when it comes to passing it to `$MyName=$_POST['myname'];` which will of course, fail. Many are not aware of this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, that is true - you would access it using the case-sensitive `$_POST['MyName']`

Comment: Yes, that I know ;-) but some don't. I always use (all) lowercase myself.